# Incessant warnings about nearing data limit

Tags: windows-10-mobile, cellular-data, data-usage

Since a few days ago my Lumia 950 has been bugging me with messages saying I'm near my data limit:

[image]

Tapping on the notification (or going into network settings manually) shows that's not the case, though - I'm only about a third of the way through my monthly limit:

[image]

I suppose, since it's only the beginning of the month, my Lumia is worried that at this pace I'll burn through my limit before the month is up. But in reality using that much mobile data in a few days is not normal for me (I had to upload a few videos to OneDrive and didn't have WiFi), so the warnings are totally unnecessary.

Can I disable these warnings somehow? I've looked around in the phone's settings but didn't find anything. Alternatively, is there a way to set the point at which the warnings will begin?

Comment: I had this issue with my Lumia 950 XL a while back.  I had to turn off the limit details, reboot the phone, and reset the limit details back to what they were.

Comment: @MaxVernon Will that also reset the data counter?

Comment: i think that will reset the data counter

Comment: Yes, it will reset.  Which is unfortunately the only workaround I could find.

Comment: It could also be a problem with your provider which has communication issues with your Lumia

Answer (score 1):

I had one such issue - This happens often when i view / stream videos in my lumia 1020.

Steps that i did;
1. Reset the data counter - default
2. Turn off the phone
3. Remove sim and replace it
4. Reboot the phone
5. Search network provider - and select your operator manually
6. Then select Automatic [Only if required and if the signal strength is low]

I had got the issue resolved.
Please try this;

Cause:
May be;
1. When the device is in automatic network - It will keep searching for the provider when if the signal strength is low or totally out.
When the Mobile data is turned on and the signal strength is low - it spends more data to search for the network - I got this information from one of the Microsoft service centres. Not sure on how is this valid but it seems to be a point.